# Any idea how the 3d rendering is handled with php in this site?

Tags: php, 3d, blender, gimp, 3d-rendering

> http://www.myecovermaker.com/ecover-design

This site renders 3d images from user selected images such as 3d books, 3d cd covers etc, I can find that site is created in php, but couldnt understand what they might be using at server end.

To my observation I find these might be possible methods

1 - They create models using 3d rendering softwares such as blender3d and some how they created a API to replace the layer and render the image from terminal.

2 - They might have used terminal interface of gimp, that they use to replace a single layer with transformation to render the image .

3 - Used any 3d libraries like ImageMagick or gd library to create unque flows for each model using user submitted images (But this is quite alot of process for each model !)

Please suggest me your ideas.

### Reference

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: So basically you want to rip off their technology ?

Comment: I think it's very likely they use PHP to tie the web frontend to some specialized 3d tool.

Comment: @HamZa Nope I just want a practical alternative that can be handled in linux terminal for a very similar project.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen you are right they are just using php as transporter and using some kind of API to render images. Now my question if this can be handled directly from a linux server with open source tools or are they using some cloud services like http://www.renderrocket.com ?

Answer (score 3):

It's using Adobe ImageReady.

You can read metadata in the png with ImageMagick.

```
identify -verbose [filename]
```

Comment: Thanks for the that info, I am not a graphics expert but is there any possibility that only 3d model was developed with ImageReady and rendering done from something else, like replacing a layer or something ? if then can meta data be same ?

Comment: Perhaps. But PNG is a format for bitmaps. It's difficult to generate new complex images from PNGs. I guess the website replaces elements in a template file (perhaps designed with an Adobe product), and renders it with imageready.